# How to highlight blockquote word if word There was inside the array using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

When the words in the array are specific blockquote word If the word is not equal or does not exist in the array "rebaz", do not highlight it const rebaz = ["something", "Hello", "BMW"]; That's just an example,I want to java script

```js
const highlightWords = (text, wordsToHighlight) => {
    const regex = new RegExp(`\\b(${wordsToHighlight.join('|')})\\b`, 'gi');

    return text.replace(regex, '<span class="highlight">$1</span>');
};


    const rebaz = ["Hello", "Volvo", "testing", "blockquote"];
```

```html
<blockquote><span class="highlight">
 Hello testing something Hello testing something Hello testing something 
</span></blockquote>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can highlight words in a blockquote if they exist in an array using JavaScript:

```js
const rebaz = ["Hello", "Volvo", "testing"]; 

const text = `Hello testing something Hello testing something Hello testing something`;

const blockquote = document.querySelector('blockquote');

const highlightedText = highlightWords(text, rebaz);

blockquote.innerHTML = highlightedText;

function highlightWords(text, words) {
  let regexp = new RegExp(`\\b(${words.join('|')})\\b`, 'gi'); 
  return text.replace(regexp, '<span class="highlight">$1</span>');
}
```

The key points:

- Create a regular expression dynamically from the array of words
- Use `text.replace()` to wrap matches with a highlight span
- Set the blockquote's `.innerHTML` to the highlighted text

This will wrap any matches in `<span class="highlight">` so you can style them. Words that don't exist in the array will not be highlighted.

Comment: Thank you very much I tried just how it will run